# Can I use Robot Framework in my Java program?

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework

I am very new at Java and Selenium so my apologies in advance if my question sounds a bit primary.

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190094/any-way-to-catch-a-webelement-without-using-xpath-or-csspath) I am suggested to use [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) . The issue is that I am using Java and need a framework in form of a jar file that I can add it to my Java program and like other jar files call its method.

Can I use this Robot Framework in this way? and if no, is there anything like that in Java?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use Maven to handle dependencies.

Use the Robotframework maven plugin that will manage the Robot Framework dependencies:

http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/

Afterwords, you will need to add the dependency to Selenium and SeliniumLibrary.

The Robot Framework and Selenium are both testing frameworks but very different:

- Robot Framework is used for acceptance test driven development where you write your test cases in text files that follow a special syntax to also make it readable by a program. Usually you will have to write so called glue code where you implement the generated test cases: Robot Framework translates the acceptance test text to Code that you can fill with the actual test implementation.
- Selenium is a UI testing tool which lets you implement tests against your web interface / UI on several browsers. It reflects the browsers DOM and simulates user interaction / user input.

  A Selenium test usually

  1. starts a browser via a driver (e.g. firefox driver, chrome etc.)
  2. goes to a specific url within that browser (usually localhost://... when developing)
  3. interacts with the website such as clicking a button
  4. validates the result e.g. a label shows "button was clicked"
  5. shuts down the browser

A combination of both is using Robot Framework **with** SeleniumLibrary which maps the keywords in a Robot test case text file to Selenium commands. See more information here:

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/04/robot-framework-tutorial-a-complete-example/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Bold added for relevant quote from the link to the [Robot Framework homepage](http://robotframework.org/) you provided;

> Robot Framework is operating system and application independent. The core framework is implemented using Python and runs also on **Jython (JVM)** and IronPython (.NET).

You would need to start by adding [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (which is Python implemented in Java).